# Slick Slider sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

I'm using slick slider for a slider on a WP page template I built for a client, and I'm running into a problem where the slider sometimes initializes okay, and sometimes it doesn't initialize at all. I can't find a solution to why is it happening.
When it doesn't initialize it just shows the slider content as full width images. Screenshots included.

This is how it looks when it's ok:
[image]

This is how it looks when it doesn't:
[image]

This is the slick slider code:

```
// Initialize slick slider
$('.sample-class').slick({
    slidesToShow: 8,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: false,
    arrows: true,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay : true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000
});
```